# Fatal Error during SPICE Simulation of CMOS inverter on Tanner-EDA S-EDIT

Tags: eda

I am trying to simulate the CMOS inverter (on the Tanner EDA S-edit tool). I am getting an error as follows -

[image]

Error: Simulation file "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Temp\inv_layout_tb.tsim" does not exist

Fatal Error: "inv_layout_tb.sp" line 24
Library File "C:\Users\TannerEDA\TannerTools_v2019.2\Process\Generic_250nm\Models\Generic_250nm. lib" not found!

and the error seems to be in this line -
**lib C:\Users\TannerEDA\TannerTools_v2019.2\Process\Generic_250nm\Models\Generic_250nm.lib" TT**

And I wanted to design the layout for this, I am using L-Edit for that.

When I tried Creating a new Design in L-Edit, it crashes showing an error that goes away as soon as I click on "OK"

Does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

P.S: I am using Windows 11, and S-edit and L-edit version 2019.2

The test bench for the above CMOS Inverter is as follows -
[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Have you found the answer? I am also using the same version as you. `"C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Temp\inv_layout_tb.tsim" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it cannot find your model file. Have you checked that it's actually located in that location set "C:\Users\TannerEDA\TannerTools_v2019.2\Process\Generic_250nm\Models\Generic_250nm.lib"

Comment: Yes, I did check. It is located in that location nset